# ERRORS: running odoo using pycharm in windows

Tags: odoo, pycharm

I have an odoo's instance Running on ubuntu server.

I shared the odoo repository so i can acces odoo's scripts from windows.

here is the configuration file:
[image: configuration]

here is the erroro that i'm getting:
[image]

Comment: you should install lxml as a pyhton package

Answer (score 0):

I've had this kind of error in past. As I remember it's your code error, not Odoo error, I can't exactly say where is the problem but definetly not odoo error

Here my configuration (it works) and check with yours, I'm too lazy to do it myself for you :D
[image]

Comment: in code i have an error on this line: from lxml import etree , unresolved reference 'lxml'